# Where can I find a link to http://careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, jobs, linked-accounts

I have an account on `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/`. I find that all my accounts on StackExchange.com are linked except http://careers.stackoverflow.com/.

- Is any link given to my career profile from any of my accounts?
- Is carrer.so account owned by StackExchange?

If user have career account then there should be link from all accounts.(I think so.)

If it is shown in user profile(by default `private` status to only logged in user) so it will be easy to access career.so acoount. <strike>If user want to show on profile, then user will set `public` status.</strike>

There is linking from career.so account to all SE accounts(as per interest which account want to show). Then why not just show link of career.so account in user profile. I am not saying it should be public. But it can be privately shown to user.(if it is managed by SE)  [image]

Comment: This question is now different than it was before. You've turned it into a feature request which makes my answer (and any others that might have bee posted) partially redundant - this should have been another question.

Comment: Should I make another question? I wanted to know about feature. But that feature doesn't exists. That's why I made it feature-request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You don't, it finds you.</strike>

These systems, although they seem 'connected' in terms of pulling data through to Careers, are distinctly different. That is to say, Careers is able to 'poll' your Stack Exchange network accounts, but your Careers account is not a Stack Exchange network account *per se* (actually, technically behind the scenes it could well be - bot not in terms of the facet through which it is exposed).

If you want to expose your Careers account in your Stack Exchange profiles then you could always place a link to it in the 'About' section of said profiles (and use the 'copy to all' feature to copy it network wide if you wish to do so.)

Comment: Why does site name career.`stackoverflow`.com?

Comment: @Somnath Muluk: Because it's a site for *programming* jobs, and careers.programmers.stackexchange.com isn't as catchy. (It pre-dates Programmers SE anyway.)